# DRCSIM: BDI modes change the hand force/torque sensor behavior

Tags: gazebo-sensor, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The hand force/torque sensor behaves well until the BDI modes are changed. While in STAND mode the output of the sensor is correct, however, when the mode is changed to MANIPULATE for example, the force/torque sensor start giving a nonsense output.

[Hand force sensor while changing BDI modes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9TETDM4PMU)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2839/drcsim:-bdi-modes-change-the-hand-force/torque-sensor-behavior/) by [Alberto Romay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/273/alberto-romay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-05-20**:
I was able to duplicate this issue using the `control_mode_switch` demo, and hacking to use a set of seemingly reasonable kd_position gains and k_effort related to moving arms and torso, but leaving legs under BDI control.  See https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/273/bdi-modes-change-the-hand-force-torque for specific gains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It was [determined](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/273/bdi-modes-change-the-hand-force-torque) that reducing the `kd_position` gains avoids this problem.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0